# Applying Euler's theorem in practice

Tags: number-theory

I want to calculate $3^{102006}\mod 101$, is my following reasoning valid?

Since GCD(101,3)=1, we may apply Euler's theorem:
$\phi(101) = 100$ therefore, $3^{100} \equiv 1 \mod 101 $.

Comment: Note that you are actually identifying $101$ as a prime, since $\phi(101) = 100$.  Therefore the conclusion $3^{100} \equiv 1 \bmod 101$ is given already by Fermat's Little Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For a basic understanding as of why, if you don't just want to see the formula as a given:

Note that multiplying by 3 multiple times can give exactly 100 outcomes, as $\phi(101) = 100$. As $3x \equiv y \mod 101$ has exactly one solution for x for any given y (that's because 3 only has one inverse), you can't get to a result from two different points. That means you eventually have to hit 1 again and go into a cycle. This cycle then has at most 100 elements and therefore $a^{100}\equiv 1 \mod 101$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I want to apply the same reasoning in $3^8 \mod 7$, it is 2 although GCD(3,7) = 1. Why it doesn't work !!!

Comment: @KateInne What makes you think it doesn't work?  Similarly, $3^6\equiv1\pmod7$.  So $3^8=3^6\times3^2\equiv1\times3^2\equiv9\equiv2\pmod7$